# Kie Server: Could not find resource for relative

Tags: tomcat, drools, kie, kie-server

I am trying to test my configured `kie server`.

I am able successfully call

```
http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/
```

It returns as expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response type="SUCCESS" msg="Kie Server info">
  <kie-server-info>
    <version>6.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </kie-server-info>
</response>
```

However when I try to send request to another url

```
http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/jobs
```

I recieve

```
HTTP Status 404 - RESTEASY001185: Could not find resource for relative : /server/jobs of full path: http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/jobs
```

Inside my `kie-server.war` I have this `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         version="2.5"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>org.kie.server.services.KieServerApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/services/rest</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>All web resources</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>kie-server</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>KIE Server</realm-name>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>kie-server</role-name>
  </security-role>

</web-app>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the KIE Server REST API with the KIE Workbench REST API. According to the documentation [[1]](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e22346), there is no `/jobs` REST endpoint in the KIE Server API.

The same documentation shows that there is a `/jobs/{jobId}` endpoint in the KIE Workbench API though.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Oh! I see. So that means that execution server works fine?

Comment: According to the response you got from `http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/`, I would say that it is.